# how to switch default hosting domain with secondary (firebase provided) one?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

Hello and thanks for your help!I have a project in the firebase console called "babalift". in the hosting panel I have 2 sites/domains : babalift.web.app and  babalift-417115.web.app. The latter and uglier is the default one, so when I deploy from the terminal that is where the index file is going to be. I would like to have the site deployed to the shorter domain "babalift.web.app". From the hosting panel i could delete the shorter one but not the default one. I wish it was the opposite.
Thanks for your baby-steps advices!

I searched and asked AI but all I get are wrong commands to terminal and not properly set up json configs...

Answer (score 0):

Running `firebase deploy` should deploy to all domains associated with your site/project. If that's not happening for you:

1. Rerun `firebase deploy`
2. If that still doesn't fix it, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting